# uninstall wubi from a bad drive

Tags: dual-boot, wubi, uninstall

I used wubi to install Ubuntu on its own hard drive. That drive seems to have died and I can no longer boot to Ubuntu. I tried to uninstall Ubuntu from the control panel in Windows 7 and received the message that it could not acces the uninstall file. I want to install Ubuntu again on another drive but am concerned about the dual boot that is already on my computer. What do you reccommend

Answer (score 0):

Simply Remove the boot entry from windows 7
and reinstall ubuntu using wubi.

read the following article 
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17903/remove-ubuntu-or-xp-from-the-windows-7-boot-menu/